# opengl 3+ buffer operations

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm interested in the process that happens when you call the various buffer functions, for example:

```
GLuint vertexbuffer;
glGenBuffers(1, &vertexbuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLfloat)*power*12, g_vertex_buffer_data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

In the tutorials that I'm following this is called after filling the vertex array with coordinates. Then inside the main loop this is called for every frame:

```
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0 );

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4*power);

glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
```

If the buffer is filled with data of a constant value, is it necessary to make these calls in every single iteration? Isn't it possible to bind the buffer before the loop, set glVertexAttribPointer and just loop and draw from the buffer?

I would be interested in the process that happens with each of these calls, for example which one instructs the cpu to send the data inside the buffer to the gpu, how long they stay there (do they reset when rendering finishes?), can the buffer data change without rebinding a whole new buffer if a few values change, so that I can figure oute which calls to make inside and outside the main loop.

Answer (score 2):

OpenGL is a *state machine*, so everything will stay the same until you explicitely request a change. The data will be copied into the buffer at the `glBufferData()` call (at least from the user's perspective. When the data will be actually sent to the GPU will be totally under control of the GL implementation. But as far as the API is concerned, after the `glBufferData` call returned, the data can be considered as to be stored in that buffer object).

Re-Setting the vertex attrib pointers for every draw call is only necessary if they actually change. Note that the reference to the currently bound `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` will become **part of the attribute pointer state** at the time of the `glVertexAttribPointer()` call, so you have to respecify the attribute pointers also if the VBO you want to draw from changes, even if all arguments of this function stay the same.
This also means that, contrary to some common misunderstanding, that it does not matter which `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` is bound when `glDrawArrays` is called.

> If the buffer is filled with data of a constant value, is it necessary
>   to make these calls in every single iteration? Isn't it possible to
>   bind the buffer before the loop, set glVertexAttribPointer and just
>   loop and draw from the buffer?

It is possible to set this state once and just have the draw call in the inner loop - as long as there are no other draw calls somewere which need a different attribute pointer state.
Note that in modern GL, there are also [Vertex Array Objects](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vao#Vertex_Array_Object) which encapsulate the vertex attrib pointer states, so you can just set up a VAO for ever object (or group of objects, or whatever draw calls you might have) once and can easily switch between them by simply binding the VAO again.

> I would be interested in the process that happens with each of these
>   calls, for example which one instructs the cpu to send the data inside
>   the buffer to the gpu,

As I already mentioned, the GL API does not expose such implementation details as when data is actually moved to the GPU (GL does not even require a GPU, there are software-only implemenatations). However, the usage hints were invented to help the GL implementation deciding where to store the buffer data. `GL_STATIC_DRAW` VBOs are likely to be transmitted only once to the GPU and stored in VRAM (if there is such a thing).

> how long they stay there (do they reset when
>   rendering finishes?),

Nothing is reset without you requesting it, and "rendering is finished" is not a meaningful concept. When would that even be?
Internally, the GL implementation might chosse to remove some buffer from VRAM if there is memory pressure, but that process is fully transparent to the user. The buffer object still exists and is useable (but performance might be worse, but that is something that can't be avoided if you're running out of memory).

> can the buffer data change without rebinding a
>   whole new buffer if a few values change, so that I can figure oute
>   which calls to make inside and outside the main loop.

I don't really fully understand that question. Buffer data does not change, even if a new buffer is bound. The whole idea of the buffer objects that they are data stores managed by the GL, but the contents are *totally* under the user's control. You can change a few bytes of buffer object, without recreating a new one.

Comment: The last part in other words: say I have a buffer of 10000 vertex attributes and 10 of them change. Is it possible to 'update' the values of just those 10 in a performance-efficient way rather than having to unbind, rebind and transfer a whole new buffer of 10000 attributes to the GPU? How would you do that?

Comment: @Tsaras: you don;t have to unbind or rebind anything at all in either case. For updating a few values: that is most efficient if those "few values" aren't scattered through the whole buffer. You can use `glBufferSubData` or, preferably, `glMapBufferRange` to update a continous sub-region of a buffer object.